# Why my laravel5.2 will showing undefine methods in DB class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I create a class and extends it form model. now i need to call mysql stored procedure which i already made in mysql database but from this model class when i use `DB::select` it shows undefine method. after using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` the problem is still there.

my code is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Domain extends Model
{
    public $table = 'english_news';

    public static function getEngNews()
    {
        return DB::select("call getUserNews");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change ::select to ::statement

Comment: paste your db fields

Answer (score 0):

From the [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects) this is the proper way you would use Laravel query builder to do a select

> $users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get(); as another example
>   $query = DB::table('users')->select('name');

Your code seems to be trying to call another function in your query which won't work in Laravel that I'm aware of. Query builder is meant to give you some flexibility in building a query in the Eloquent structure.

Comment: I am trying to call a stored procedure that i write in mysql database.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-stored-procedures?page=1 That addresses your question I believe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `DB::statement('call getUserNews');` ? This is the recommended way to write hardcoded sql statements using the Laravel's DB facade. Take a look at the `statement` section in https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Open command line for creating one model:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName
```

Now one file will create in App folder.
Open that file,

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ModalName extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'english_news'; //Fill this portion.
}
```

In Controller:

```
public static function getEngNews()
{
    return ModalName::select("getUserNews");
}
```